# How do I prevent CoreWCF base address from being overriden by Kestrel?

Tags: c#, kestrel-http-server, kestrel, corewcf

I am initializing a **CoreWCF** service using Kestrel as a host. The code goes as follows:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices();
builder.WebHost.UseNetTcp(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(address), int.Parse(port));
builder.WebHost.UseUrls(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}", address, port));
builder.Logging.AddConsole().AddDebug();

service = builder.Build();

service.UseServiceModel(builder =>
{
    builder.AddService<ServiceImpl>();
    builder.AddServiceEndpoint<ServiceImpl, IService>(binding, endpoint);
});

Task startupTask = service.StartAsync();
startupTask.Wait();
```

The binding is a **NetTcpBinding**. The **address** is "127.0.0.1" and the **port** is "8001". **endpoint** is "/endpoint". The intention is to have a service that listens at "net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8001/endpoint".

Note: this is supposed to be a quick-and-dirty prototype designed for understanding how WCF services can be migrated to CoreWCF & Kestrel as a host.

During start up, the console output reads:

> ```bash
> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>       Overriding address(es) 'net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8001'. Binding to > endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
>       Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:8001
> ```

There is no configuration file in this application, no json, etc. The code presented contains the configuration. Why is the URI I specified via **UseUrls** being overriden and how do I fix it?

Comment: Why `tartupTask.Wait();` instead of `await service.StartAsync()` ?

Comment: The enclosing method is not defined as async. I think await requires the caller to be async. Maybe I'm wrong, I didn't check, but that was the reasoning.

Comment: Top-level programs are async, or rather, the top-level code is wrapped in an `async` Main function by the compiler